# Block GET request to a directory with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to block all `HTTP GET` requests to a directory which contain videos and images like `upload` folder. And if user is coming with `HTTP POST` than allow user to access. Currently I am using

```
#Contents of .htaccess

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^PATH.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^PATH.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .(mp4|mp3|avi)$ - [F]
```

But its blocking all request. I want to access this with `HTTP POST` request.

Please help me with this.

Comment: "And if user is coming with HTTP POST than allow user to access." - Why would you need to allow POST requests to a directory that contains videos and images?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following `mod-rewrite` based solution to block all `GET` requests for `upload` folder.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} GET\s/upload [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```

Or

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} GET
RewriteRule ^upload - [F,L]
```

Comment: I used this but the directory is accessing by the `HTTP GET` I want to block it when user comes with `GET` but not when user comes with `HTTP POST`

Comment: @TheIRF This does work. Try placing the code at the top of your htaccess.

Comment: This is the only script in my file.

Comment: Let me clear on thing I am testing it through `PostMan` and sending request direct to the file like `http://localhost/Test/uploads/Full-Send_3.mp4` with the method `POST` & `GET` and still getting that file.

Comment: It worked but one more thing I have sub-directories how to restrict that to?

Comment: @TheIRF The example in your question used `upload` as the folder. But you are testing `/Test/uploads/...`. This solution already restricts subdirectories. +1

Answer (score 0):

You need to write the htaccess rules that will allow only post request.
Follow this following script.

```
<Directory "/var/www/folder">
    <Files "index.php">
        Require method POST
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

However, since that's part of the authorization section, you may want to try this instead:

```
<Directory "/var/www/folder">
    <Files "index.php">
        <LimitExcept POST>
            Order allow,deny
            Deny from all
        </LimitExcept>
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I try your code with replacing `/var/www/folder` to `http://localhost/Test/` it returns `Internal Server Error`

Comment: No, It would be your directory path not your browser url

Comment: I replaced it with `F:\Work\htdocs\project\upload` and try to get it with `HTTP POST` but returning `500 Internal Server Error`

Comment: try by giving /project/upload

Comment: which server your are using? is it xampp or lamp? name your OS too?

Comment: Is this path is from where my htaccess file is placed? or from my index file?

Comment: I am using xampp

Comment: this is where you project is located, root directory of your project

Comment: Directory directive can not be used in `htaccess` You can use `FilesMatch` or `mod-rewrite` instead .

Comment: Why are you using a `<Files "index.php">` wrapper? You are using Apache 2.4 directives in your first example, but Apache 2.2 directives in your second?

Answer (score 0):

You could also do something like the following using an Apache 2.4 expression in `.htaccess`:

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/upload/#">
    Require method POST
</If>
```

Any URL-path that starts `/upload/` will be blocked, unless it is a POST request.

Comment: Thanks For Look into it. But sorry didn't work.

Comment: And one more thing this script is for custom CMS like wordpress